# Shared .settings files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

In ProjectA I Add New Item -> Settings File ... I call it "Shared.Settings".
Edit the settings and I set the Access Modifier to be Public. 
In ProjectB I Add EXISTING Item -> Select that Settings File and "Add As Link"

This all seems to work great until I deploy ProjectA and I then need to edit Settings. Copying  Shared.Settings into the output folder doesn't seem to work ... it's not read at runtime \ load time.

How to I edit the ProjectB settings for that deployed ProjectA now?

Comment: You need to load the configuration file manually if you want to what you describe.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm a little confused between the App.Config files and the xxx.settings files. Can you load the xxx.setting files using ConfigurationManager?

Comment: The settings files determine what will be contained in the app.config file.  If you don't have values contained in the settings then the app.config file is empty.